# SQL stored procedure; using input parameter to call another stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

Let's say we have a stored procedure that looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1(@sp1Param NVARCHAR(256))
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp2 @sp2Param = @sp1Param
END
```

Is this a correct way to use `sp1Param` to call `sp2`? All I need to know is if this should work (which would mean my problem is inside `sp2`)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```
USE tempdb
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp1(@param1 int) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @param1 + 1
END
GO

EXEC sp1 2 -- should return 3
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_wrap(@param2 int) AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp1 @param1 = @param2
END
GO

EXEC sp_wrap 4 -- should return 5
GO

DROP PROCEDURE sp_wrap
DROP PROCEDURE sp1
GO
```